# Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter: struct

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, closures

I have the following code I'm using with SwiftUI:

```
import Foundation

public struct Trigger {
    public var value = false

    public mutating func toggle() {
        value = true
        let responseDate = Date().advanced(by: 3)

        OperationQueue.main.schedule(after: .init(responseDate)) {
            moveBack()
        }
    }

    private mutating func moveBack() {
        value = false
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

[image]

I understand that changing the struct to a class would solve this issue, but is there any way to actually capture a mutating self in an escaping closure in a struct?

Comment: No.  View models should almost always be classes, and they pretty much have to be if you ant to mutate the model

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you have found, the quick solution is to use a *reference type*, a *class*.  But why is this the case?

Swift structs are value types, so they are immutable.  You can mark a function as `mutating` to indicate to the compiler that a function mutates the struct, but what does that actually mean?

Consider a simple struct:

```
struct Counter {
   var count

   init(_ count: Int = 0)
   {
       self.count = count
   }

   mutating func increment() {
       self.count+=1
   }
}
```

Now, try and assign an instance of this to a `let` constant:

```
let someCounter = Counter()
someCounter.increment()
print(someCounter.count)
```

You will get an error; you need to use a `var`.

```
var someCounter = Counter()
someCounter.increment()
print(someCounter.count)
```

What actually happens when you call a `mutating` func is that a *new `Counter`* is created, with the new `count` and it is assigned to `someCounter`. It is effectively saying `someCounter = Counter(someCounter.count+1)`

Now, think what would happen if you could mutate `self` in an escaping closure - That new `Counter` is going to be created at some unspecified time in the future, but execution has already moved on.  It is too late to update `someCounter`.

The other advantage of using a `class`, as you have found, is that you can use `ObservableObject`, which makes updating your SwiftUI views much easier.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed explanation. The only reason why I started to look into the `struct` solution is that I wasn't able to configure the `ObservableObject` solution in a first place.

Comment: Excellent explanation. (Voted). I was going to try to explain it, but you beat me to it, and probably did better than I would have.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I finished with:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

public final class IntervalTrigger: ObservableObject {
    private let timeInterval: TimeInterval
    @Published var value = false

    public init(_ timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        self.timeInterval = timeInterval
    }

    public func toggle() {
        value = true
        let responseDate = Date().advanced(by: timeInterval)
        OperationQueue.main.schedule(after: .init(responseDate)) { [weak self] in
            self?.value = false
        }
    }
}
```